# extract items from column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
  id    year  name        genres        
  238   2022  Adventure   [{"revenue": 1463, "name": "culture clash", 'runtime': 150, 'vote_average': 7}]
 239    2020  Comedy   []
```

But what I need is this structure

```
 id    year  name           revenue  name           runtime vote_average
 238   2022  Adventure      1463     culture clash  150       7
 239    2020  Comedy
```

Please note that i sometimes have empty array in column **genres**

i used this code

```
(df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['genres'], record_path='genres'), 
               lsuffix='', rsuffix='_genres')
```

but it got me an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:
In case the `genres` columns contains strings do

```
df["genres"] = df["genres"].map(eval)
```

fist. Then:

```
df = pd.concat(
    [df[["id", "year"]], pd.DataFrame(obj[0] if obj else {} for obj in df["genres"])],
    axis="columns"
)
```

Result for the sample:

```
    id  year  revenue           name  runtime  vote_average
0  238  2022   1463.0  culture clash    150.0           7.0
1  239  2020      NaN            NaN      NaN           NaN
```

If you don't want use `eval` you could try this

```
df["genres"] = pd.read_json("[" + ", ".join(df["genres"]) + "]")
df = pd.concat(
    [df[["id", "year"]], pd.json_normalize(df["genres"])], axis="columns"
)
```

instead.

Comment: I got a column labled 0 with `[` value

Comment: @Prestige My guess would be that your genres column contains strings, not lists? If that's the case do `df["genres"] = df["genres"].map(eval)` first.

Answer (score 0):

Personally speaking, I would use `iterrows` in your case:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  value = row["genres"]
  if len(value) == 1:
    for key, keyValue in value[0].items():
      df.loc[index, key] = keyValue 
df.drop(columns=["genres"], inplace=True)
df
```

##### Output

|  | id | year | revenue | name | runtime | vote_average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 238 | 2022 | 1463 | culture clash | 150 | 7 |
| 1 | 239 | 2020 | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: I got error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`